# Application failed when changing user cession windows 7

Tags: c++, windows-7

I have an application witch run on local admin account with MFC and user interface.
When i change logon windows 7 cession,  Application failed.

How can i keep the application alive when changing windows cession?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/225df895-4e94-4bb0-b25e-17e2bb1d6ec5/

Comment: Use WTSRegisterSessionNotification and WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE. Sorry!

Comment: Doesnt work, i catch this but the application still crash. Can Anybody explain why the application isnt running anymore when changing cession? It works fine when im listenning MP3 ;o)